# How to do null combination in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, isnull

Here's my dataset

```
Id    Column_A    Column_B    Column_C
1         Null           7        Null
2            8           7        Null
3         Null           8           7
4            8        Null           8
```

If at least one column is null, Combination will be Null

```
Id    Column_A    Column_B    Column_C   Combination
1         Null           7        Null         Null
2            8           7        Null         Null
3         Null           8           7         Null
4            8        Null           8         Null
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Null` is NaN, we could use `isna` + `any`:

```
df['Combination'] = df.isna().any(axis=1).map({True: 'Null', False: 'Notnull'})
```

If `Null` is a string, we could use `eq` + `any`:

```
df['Combination'] = df.eq('Null').any(axis=1).map({True: 'Null', False: 'Notnull'})
```

Output:

```
   Id Column_A Column_B Column_C Combination
0   1     Null        7     Null        Null
1   2        8        7     Null        Null
2   3     Null        8        7        Null
3   4        8     Null        8        Null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Combination'] = np.where(df.isna().any(axis=1), 'Null','Notnull')
df['Combination'] = np.where(df.eq('Null').any(axis=1), 'Null','Notnull')
```